# How do I best create a function to perform the following sums

Tags: r

For a sequence of numbers x, how do I best create a function `S(x, r, s)` that computes `sum(x[t]*x[t+r-s]`, where `t` ranges from `s` to `length(x)-r+1` and `r,s > 0`.

Comment: Nothing is surely wrong with the hobby of learning by doing and asking questions that help do it better. The only thing superior is learning by teaching.

Comment: @LarryWatanabe be nice.. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to enforce a relationship between the length of x, and the values of s and r as well, or you can end up with some strange results. Try 6:1 for instance.

```
sumfunc <- function(x, s, r) {
   s <- s[s>0]
   r <- r[r>0]
   if(!(length(r)==1 && length(s)==1)) stop("s and r should be numbers > 0")
   t <- s:(length(x)-r+1)
   return(sum(x[t]*x[t+r-s]))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Shane. If not by looking at what Masters are doing, how else I know what's best.